# Batch File - Drag and drop INTO console window?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know you can use %1 if you drag a file onto a batch file, but can you drag and drop a file INTO the console window? Like if I started a batch file and it said:

```
Drag and drop a file below:
[   ]
```

and when you drag a file into the console window it said:

```
Drag and drop a file below:
[Some File.txt]
```

Anyone know how you can do this? Even with utilities?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/51140/dragging-and-dropping-folders-onto-the-command-prompt-in-windows-vista-server-20

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
@echo off
echo Drag and drop a file or enter file name with keyboard.
set /P "FileName=Hit ENTER when done: "
echo Dropped file is: %FileName%
pause
```

But the user of the batch file must hit ENTER respectively RETURN after dropping the file into the console window to continue batch execution.

The last 2 lines are only for getting the file (or folder) name displayed after hitting ENTER or RETURN for verification.

Note: I have read that this does not work on Windows Vista/Server 2008 which I can't verify by myself. But it works on Windows XP and Windows 7 as verified by me.